# How to convert this list in python to the given form

Tags: python-2.7

I have a list in this format :-

```
j1=['t1', ['xl(a)', 'w(a)', 'xl(c)', 'w(c)', 'xl(b)', 'w(b)', 'ul(a)', 'ul(b)', 'ul(c)'], 't2', ['xl(b)', 'r(b)', 'w(b)', 'xl(a)', 'r(a)', 'w(a)', 'ul(b)', 'ul(a)'], 't3', ['xl(b)', 'w(b)', 'r(b)', 'ul(b)']]
```

and I want to change it into

```
j1=[['t1', ['xl(a)', 'w(a)', 'xl(c)', 'w(c)']], ['t2', ['xl(b)', 'r(b)', 'w(b)', 'xl(a)']], ['t3', ['xl(b)', 'w(b)', 'r(b)', 'ul(b)']],['t1',['xl(b)', 'w(b)', 'ul(a)', 'ul(b)'],['t2',['r(a)', 'w(a)', 'ul(b)', 'ul(a)']],['t1',['ul(c)']]]
```

that is at most 4 items within list items of t1 , t2 or t3.
how do i perform the conversion I want to apply round robin actually

Comment: do you have any code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple set of loops and checks:

```
answer=[]
head=[]
tails=[]
for x,y in enumerate(j1):
  if x%2==0:
    head.append(y)
  else:
    tails.append(y)

stillmore = True;
while stillmore == True:
  for i,z in enumerate(tails):
    temp = []
    if len(z)>0:
      temp.append(z.pop(0))
    if len(z)>0:
      temp.append(z.pop(0))
    if len(z)>0:
      temp.append(z.pop(0))
    if len(z)>0:
      temp.append(z.pop(0))
    if len(temp)>0:
      doub=[]
      doub.append(head[i])
      doub.append(temp)
      answer.append(doub)
  left=0
  for z in tails:
    left=left+len(z)
  if left == 0:
    stillmore = False
print answer
```

There must be other compressed ways to express this, but this is fairly clear what it is doing.

Comment: Thanks but it is giving me output as ['t1', ['xl(a)', 'w(a)', 'xl(c)', 'w(c)'], 't2', ['xl(b)', 'r(b)', 'w(b)', 'xl(a)'], 't3', ['xl(b)', 'w(b)', 'r(b)', 'ul(b)']] and I want it to be j1=[['t1', ['xl(a)', 'w(a)', 'xl(c)', 'w(c)']], ['t2', ['xl(b)', 'r(b)', 'w(b)', 'xl(a)']], ['t3', ['xl(b)', 'w(b)', 'r(b)', 'ul(b)']],['t1',['xl(b)', 'w(b)', 'ul(a)', 'ul(b)'],['t2',['r(a)', 'w(a)', 'ul(b)', 'ul(a)']],['t1',['ul(c)']]]

Comment: I want it to iterate till the whole list exhausts forming group of 4 !

Comment: output comes [['t1', ['xl(a)', 'w(a)', 'xl(c)', 'w(c)']], ['t2', ['xl(b)', 'r(b)', 'w(b)', 'xl(a)']], ['t3', ['xl(b)', 'w(b)', 'r(b)', 'ul(b)']]] , I want it to be [['t1', ['xl(a)', 'w(a)', 'xl(c)', 'w(c)']], ['t2', ['xl(b)', 'r(b)', 'w(b)', 'xl(a)']], ['t3', ['xl(b)', 'w(b)', 'r(b)', 'ul(b)']],['t1',['xl(b)', 'w(b)', 'ul(a)', 'ul(b)'],['t2',['r(a)', 'w(a)', 'ul(b)', 'ul(a)']],['t1',['ul(c)']]]  that is iterate till the list exhausts